# Где настраивается прокси для работы менеджера обновлений в ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy

Менеджер обновлений выдает такие вот ошибки

> `W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required`

Где ему прописать настройки прокси? Так же не устанавливаются пакеты через apt-get.

Comment: а что у вас есть прокси?

Comment: да, система через прокси ходит в нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

['apt-get' does not work with Proxy][1]  [1]: https://askubuntu.com/questions/23666/apt-get-does-not-work-with-proxy

Comment: вах, спасибо помог. поправил /etc/apt/apt.conf, если кому интересно

Answer (score 0):

в консоли: export http_proxy=http://proxy-server:port/

либо это же в .bashrc

либо:

на постоянно:/etc/apt/apt.conf, в нём Acquire::http::Proxy "http://server:port/";